# How do I make floor plan directions?

Tags: html, google-maps

Im currently thinking of making floor plan direction for my school. It has 2 floors and various portables (Classroom outside).

[The floor plan im trying to utilize.](https://dl-web.dropbox.com/get/public/EckNav/school.pdf?_subject_uid=80133010&w=AACVWprilRFSqGknHkMsp6M_e4k1X-2f_4LQ7Qdf7D88NQ)

I tried physically annotating each individual classrooms to classrooms. But this is very tedious. Using google maps? or html? can I make a simple floor plan page that links all the classrooms just like google maps?

Imagine, a user wants to get from room 123 to room 153. The user wants to use the application to show the route on the floorplan of how to get from that particular room to the other.

The floor plan direction site is going to give the user option of from then to and it will show the direction.

For a 100 room school, there could be possibly 1000 ways to get from there to there.

Is there any way of doing this? Given the fact that the application would need to pretty much know exactly where all the possible routes are, this is something pretty much exactly like Google maps.

It would be great if we could use Google Map's api to create directions around a custom floor-plan, but I'm pretty sure this is not possible!

Anyone know any easier way of achieving this possibility?
Any advise on what direction to take would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

JeremyZh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looked at https://www.google.com/maps/about/partners/indoormaps/? There is also an app to map out the building with your phone: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.insight.surveyor&hl=de

Comment: Yeah... but i need floor plan navigation app, not just the floor plan mapper.